# Poner contenido de una subconsulta en un campo de una tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, python, angular, flask, python-3.7

Buen Dia.

Estoy realizando una app que imprime los registros de una base MySQL en una tabla de Angular. Sin embargo, tengo problemas para realizar lo siguiente:

Tengo los siguientes foros:

```
  autoevaluacion
  rt_funcionarios
  reporteadores
  reporteadores_gerentes
  rt_gerentes
  contrato_funcionarios
  rt_jefes
  contrato_gerentes
```

cada uno tiene su propio campo dentro de la tabla de la BD. Lo que estoy intentando es realizar es una subconsulta que me traiga el valor de cada foros y los meta en otro campo, pero me sale un error.

Codigo Flask

```
@app.route('/consultaUsuarios', methods = ["POST"])
def consulta_usuarios():
    conection = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root','root', 'users')
    cursor = conection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT nombre, email, rol,(SELECT autoevaluacion, rt_funcionarios, reporteadores, reporteadores_gerentes, rt_gerentes, contrato_funcionarios, rt_jefes,contrato_gerentes FROM administrador_usuarios) FROM administrador_usuarios")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    field_name = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    json_string = [{description: value for description, value in zip(field_name, row+(True,False))} for row in data]
    print("Resultado : ", json_string)
    return jsonify(json_string)
    conection.close()
```

Y el error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
File "C:\Users\ERICKE~1\DOCUME~1\PROYEC~1\FOROS-~1\forosenv\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

Como puedo realizar correctamente este requerimiento?

Comment: Si quieres todos esos campos de la subconsulta, debes ponerla en el from como una tabla más, hacer el join con las demás que consideres relevante e incluir en el SELECT los campos de esa "tabla" que deseas. Para poner la subconsulta directo en el SELECT, tienes que dar una sola columna

Comment: ¿Para que usas una subconsulta? es la misma tabla son las mismas condiciones de selcción

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta que tu subconsulta esta regresando varios campo y debería ser solo uno ya que lo estas poniendo como parte de un campo en la consulta principal. aparte las dos consultas son de la misma tabla administrador_usuarios

```
(SELECT autoevaluacion FROM administrador_usuarios) as camporesultado
```

lo que puedes hacer es un inner join con tus dos tablas